# Why can two variables have the same name?

Tags: java

I execute the following code and I get no errors, and in the output I see the `Success!` message. Can you please explain this strange behaviour.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int р = 0;
        int p = 1;
        if(р == 0 && p == 1) {
            System.out.println("Success!");
        }

    }
```

---

[You can check the online demo](https://ideone.com/K1qJcX)

Comment: They don't have the same name. When I try to search for "int p =" on my browser, only the second variable is found. The first one must be using a different character that looks like 'p'.

Comment: @Erwin did you read the question? The issue is not with `р == 0 && p == 1`  evaluated to true. It's about two variables that seem to have the same name.

Comment: This is all pretty well explained in the Unicode-related answers to the duplicate question. Since you're also looking into situations where seemingly, one variable has two values are the same time, this is the right duplicate as this duplicates looks into how to make a variable appear to be equal to 3 values at the same time, and many of the answers use Unicode to create variables with different names that look the same when they're viewed

Comment: When you paste that letter into URL address field, Google suggests some Russian words.

Comment: @Eran Yes Eran - see my explanation above that I was just typing. I've added another duplicate that more explicitly answers the same question.

Comment: you can add [ideone demo](https://ideone.com/K1qJcX) to your question to make it clear

Comment: @YCF_L It would be nice of you if you can make an edit to the question =)

Comment: I've seen at least one or two variations of this question in the last few days mmm...

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I've checked your post and you talked about using the same variable in multiple tests in the same `if` and you solved it with a multi threading technic, in the other hand my post was about the naming of a variable which turned out to be different `p` according to JonSkeet, do you see any threading in my post? I don't see any correspondance between my post and yours. , I believe that my post is obviously not a duplicate. I demande to reopen it.

Comment: @ziMtyth I didn't close it as a duplicate (this time) - the fact that it was closed again by someone else is a clear indication that it *is* a duplicate. In fact, the second link has one answer that describes exactly the same situation as in the answer that you accepted below. And for the other duplicate, I didn't refer to the threading answer but to the unicode answers, as I explained above. In any case, if you believe a closure is incorrect or that you have fixed your question, you can click the "reopen" link under your question and nominate it for re-opening.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

both are different variables (but looks similar), you can see the UTF-16  is different

```
    int р = 0;
    int p = 1;
    if (р == 0 && p == 1) {
        System.out.println("Success!");
        System.out.println("p UTF-16 is " + (int) 'p');
        System.out.println("р UTF-16 is " + (int) 'р');
    }
```

output

```
Success!
p UTF-16 is 112
р UTF-16 is 1088
```

Comment: how do you explain this?

Comment: @ziMtyth I checked this on my IDE

Comment: Note that 1088 is *not* an ASCII value. ASCII only goes up to 127. What you're looking at is the UTF-16 code unit.

Comment: @Saravana I don't say it doesn't work, I say how do you explain it?

Comment: @ziMtyth: It's not clear what you're asking to be explained. There are two different characters, which happen to be displayed very similarly. One is a lower-case 'p', the other is ["cyrillic small letter ER"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0440/index.htm)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, corrected it.

Comment: @Saravana and JonSkeet thank you for the explanation =)

Comment: this is scary. can bog down a programmer endlessly. :-o